# Convert 10001101101 (binary) to base 4

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I did

$$10001101101_{2} = \\ 1*2^{0}+0*2^1+1*2^2+1*2^3+0*2^4+1*2^5+1*2^6+0*2^7+0*2^8+0*2^9+1*2^{10} = \\
1*4^0+1*4^1+2*4^1+2*4^2+1*4^3+2*4^3+1*4^5 = \\
1*4^0 + 3*4^1 + 2*4^2+3*4^3+0*4^4+1*4^5 = \\
103231\_{4} $$

The answer should be 101231. What went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When converting from binary to base four, you can just convert the bits two-by-two (since $4$ is a power of $2$):
$$
10001101101_2=1\,00\,01\,10\,11\,01_2\\
=1\,0\,1\,2\,3\,1_4=101231_4
$$
As to where you went wrong, your $2\cdot 4^3$ shouldn't be there as you have $0\cdot 2^7$.

Comment: Ohh I see. I solved it as if it was 1*2^7. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be $1*2^6+\color{red}0*2^7=1*4^3+\color{red}0*2*4^3=\color{red}1*4^3$, not $3*4^3$

Comment: That's what I did...

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire:   I added more to my answer to highlight where you went wrong

Answer (score 0):

You computed $0 \cdot 2^7$ as if it was $1 \cdot 2^7$ and added the term $2 \cdot 4^3$ to third line.

---

By the base b expansion theorem,

$(10001101101)_2$

$= (1\cdot 2^{10}) + (0\cdot  2^{9}) + (0\cdot  2^{8}) + (0\cdot  2^{7}) + (1\cdot  2^{6}) + (1\cdot  2^{5}) + (0\cdot  2^{4}) + (1\cdot  2^{3}) + (1\cdot  2^{2}) + (0\cdot 2^{1}) + (1\cdot2^{0})$

$= 1024 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 64 + 32 + 0 + 8 + 4 + 0 + 1$

$=1024 + 64 + 32 + 8 + 4 + 1$

$=4^5 + 4^3 + (2 \cdot 4^2) + (2\cdot 4^1) + 4^1 + 4^0$

$=4^5 + 4^3 + (2 \cdot 4^2) + (3\cdot 4^1) + 4^0$

$=4^5 + 0 + 4^3 + (2 \cdot 4^2) + (3\cdot 4^1) + 4^0$

$=4^5 + (0 \cdot 4^0) + 4^3 + (2 \cdot 4^2) + (3\cdot 4^1) + 4^0$

$=(1 \cdot 4^5) + (0 \cdot 4^0) + (1 \cdot 4^3) + (2 \cdot 4^2) + (3\cdot 4^1) + (1\cdot 4^0)$

$=(101231)_4$

---

Also, since $4$ is the $2$nd power of $2$, there is a trick you can use in which you evaluate every pair of digits, from right to left...

$10001101101$

$1.00.01.10.11.01$

$101231$

Since $(01)_2=(1)_4, (11)_2=(3)_4, (10)_2=(2)_4, (00)_2=(0)_4$

Answer (score 0):

$$10001101101_2 = 1133$$

$4^0 = 1$
$4^1 = 4$
$4^2 = 16$
$4^3 = 64$
$4^4 = 256$
$4^5 = 1024$
$4^6 = 4096$

The largest up to 1133 is 1024. The sixth place must be a 1.

$1133 - 1024 = 109$

The largest up to 109 is 64. The fourth place must be a 1.

$109 - 64 = 45$

The largest up to 45 is 16. $45 / 16 = 2 r 13$ The second place must be a 2

The largest up to 13 is 4. $13 / 4 = 3 r 1$ The one place must be a 3

The zero place must be 1.